# A subgroup of index $2$ has to be normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

Lang gives the above example in his book. My interpretation is that by saying "then the kernel of our homomorphism is normal of index $2$, hence equal to $H$". His reasoning is that $H$ has to be contained in the kernel. Then being of the same index implies that they have the same order, thus they should be equal to each other. However, this should only work in the situation where $H$ is finite. Am I right?

Comment: As MooS explained this follows from a general fact from group theory. A proof can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730728/if-k-leq-h-leq-g-show-that-gk-ghhk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this proof works for any group. If we have two subgroups of the same finite index, and one is contained in the other, then they are equal. The cardinality of the group is not relevant for this, only the finiteness of the index is needed.